# Getting undefined in dynamically calling sibling in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I am newbie to jquery. In my code I dynamically generate the radio button in jquery.when user clicked on the radio button I should get the siblings value.here is my jsp code.

```
<div id="result">
                                    <c:forEach var="user" items="${model.userList}">

                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Name</td>

                                                    <td>Is Approver</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <c:forEach var="disp" items="${user.value}">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><c:out
                                                                value="${disp.getTblUserDetails().getUserName()}" /></td>

                                                        <td class="phase" style="display:none"><c:out value='${user.key.getId()}'/></td>
                                                        <td class="users" style="display:none"><c:out value='${disp.getTblUserDetails().getId()}'/></td>

                                                        <td><input type="radio" name="approver" class="some" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </tbody>

                                        </table>

                                    </c:forEach>
                                    </div>
```

My Jquery code:

```
$("#result").on("click",".some",function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                   var phaseid= $(this).siblings('.phase').val();
                   var userid=$(this).siblings('.users').val();
                   alert(userid+" "+phaseid);
                });
```

I am getting undefined in alert box.what's wrong with my code.how to I get siblings.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings('.phase')` instead of `$(this).siblings('.phase')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.some` is the input element inside a `td` so the `.phase` and `.users` are not siblings of `this`, they are the siblings of the parent of `this`. So

```
$("#result").on("click", ".some", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    var phaseid = $td.siblings('.phase').text();
    var userid = $td.siblings('.users').text();
    alert(userid + " " + phaseid);
});
```

Also `td` does not have value, you may have to use `.text()`